# Segmentation Fault On New

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault, new-operator

I'm not sure if this is a problem with g++ or somehow my compiler is messed up but I am getting an error on new at the very start of my program. I have tested everything and it any instance of new gives me a fault, even something as simple as this:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    new char[12];
    return 0;
}
```

Stack Trace:

```
#0  0x7703636d in ntdll!RtlAllocateHeap () from C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\ntdll.dll
#1  0x77035125 in ntdll!RtlAllocateHeap () from C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\ntdll.dll
#2  0x77034fc2 in ntdll!RtlAllocateHeap () from C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\ntdll.dll
#3  0x770cece6 in ntdll!RtlpNtSetValueKey () from C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\ntdll.dll
#4  0x77037656 in ntdll!RtlAllocateHeap () from C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\ntdll.dll
#5  0x77035125 in ntdll!RtlAllocateHeap () from C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\ntdll.dll
#6  0x77034fc2 in ntdll!RtlAllocateHeap () from C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\ntdll.dll
#7  0x765e79b0 in msvcrt!malloc () from C:\WINDOWS\System32\msvcrt.dll
#8  0x6fef4a79 in ?? () from C:\MinGW\bin\libstdc++-6.dll
#9  0x6fef4a1f in ?? () from C:\MinGW\bin\libstdc++-6.dll
#10 0x00401a5c in main (argc=2, argv=0x7679b0) at C:\Users\Mackenzie\Desktop\School\ECE150\Project\Parser\parser.cpp:2
```

Comment: What exactly is the point in doing `new char[12];`???

Comment: Probably a bad installation or some DLL hell.

Comment: How do you build this?

Comment: @barakmanos I just deduced the problem down to something as simple as trying to allocate memory.

Comment: Where is the name of the variable in `new char[12];` ?

Comment: @n.m. I am using CLion for my ide (Cmake 3.6.2) and MinGW 3.22 for the compiler

Comment: @J.Piquard `new char[12]` is a valid C++ expression. An expression followed by a semicolon is a valid C++ statement, A valid program is not required to make any sense.

Comment: Try typing a compilation command in a terminal window.

Comment: @n.m., Yes, I know, but why creating a software with a non-sense expression ?

Comment: @J.Piquard To demonstrate a problem with a compiler.

Comment: @Goodwin, Is a more-sense expression like `char *toto = new char[12];` working as expected when compile with that compiler ?

Comment: I suggest it is more likely that your compiler/library installation is messed up

Comment: @Peter Switch to the VS compiler works now.